# Парсинг новостей сайта по дате добавления

Tags: java, android, jsoup, парсер, java-hashmap

Как парсить новости с помощью JSOUP, по дате добавления? 
Если просто парсить, а потом добавлять в ListView, выводит не по порядку.
Я так понимаю, наверное надо брать дату с сайта, также с помощью JSOUP, а потом их сравнивать?

**UPD.**
    Вот код, здесь я парсю title статьи и его ссылку на полную статью.

```
  public class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask> {
        @Override
        protected HashMap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://xn--b1adgibfvfjyf6j.xn--p1ai/").get();
                Elements elements = document.select(".article-header");
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    Element elementUrl = element.select("a[href]").first(); //парсим ссылку на новость
                    hashMap.put(element.text(), elementUrl.attr("abs:href"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO automatic init
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

return hashMap;
    }
}

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Если нивости у вас не по порядку, значит вы их не правильно парсите.

Comment: Выложил код парсинга title статей и их URL ведущие на полную статью.
Только к AsyncTask добавить AsyncTask<Void,Void,HashMap<String,String>>

Если так парсить не правильно, укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что класс `HashMap` [не хранит](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/hashmap.php) записи в порядке их добавления. О этого у вас и вразнобой идут спарсенные значения.

Используйте [`LinkedHashMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683524/3212712). В нём информация хранится в порядке её добавления.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вам. 
Как же я мог забыть про LinkedHashMap.:(